# MS Word 10 table won't delete

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I created a table. Now everytime I start Word 10 the initial table I started with comes up instead of a blank document. I have tried many different ways to delete the table but everytime I re-open Word the table pops up.

Answer (score 2):

By default, user templates are stored in the following location:

In Windows XP:
`C:\Documents and Settings\<user name>\Application Data\Microsoft\Templates`

In Windows Vista/7:
`C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates`

Try this:

1. Open a new document.
2. Delete the table and set any other options you'd like to be the default for all new documents, such as document content, fonts, styles, language, margins, zoom level and so on.
3. Save the document as **Normal.dotm** (**Important**: The *Save as type* should be **Word Macro-Enabled Template** (i.e. with the **.dotm** extension), as shown below:

   [image: Word 2010 Template]
4. Close Word.
5. Now navigate to the template location mentioned above, as appropriate for your Windows version (you can type **%AppData%\Microsoft\Templates** in the Start/Run dialog or the Start Menu search field as a shortcut to get there).
6. You will find the existing copy of **Normal.dotm** there. Rename it to something like **Normal.dotm.old** or delete it, your choice.
7. Move your new **Normal.dotm** (created in step 3 above) to the same location the old one was in.
8. Now restart Word and check if you get a new document every time with all the properties you selected above in step 2.

Comment: @gina: Excellent! :) Since you're new here, be sure to accept the answer if it helped you.