# Delete default template in Microsoft Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

A default template has accidentally been made and continues to open on start up of Excel. How can I delete a default template in 2010?

Answer (score 7):

Unlike Word, Excel doesn't have a [Normal template](https://superuser.com/a/478029/138343).

What you can look for however is **Book.xlt/.xltx/.xltm** and **Sheet.xlt/.xltx/.xltm** under

`%APPDATA%\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART`

or

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\XLSTART` (the folder name *Program Files (x86)* can vary)

**Book.xlt** is used as the basis for new workbooks, and similarly **Sheet.xlt** is used as the basis for new worksheets added to existing workbooks.

Comment: I believe the path should be `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART` (withouth the `Roaming` which is already in %APPDATA%).

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple places to check.  See the list under the third option on this page:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/customize-how-excel-starts-HP005199391.aspx

It says Excel 2003 but apparently this is still applicable.